# Should we remove the suggestion for nutrition questions to be directed to the Fitness and Nutrition stack exchange?

Tags: discussion, site-faq

In the Skeptics FAQ we say:

> If your question is not about a particular claim, or if it is about research-level science, the following sites may be better suited for your needs:
>
> - Physics - Physics - Stack Exchange
> - Nutrition - Fitness and Nutrition - Stack Exchange

However, in the Fitness and Nutrition FAQ, they say that questions about "nutrition unrelated to exercise, such as food safety, nutritional needs for children, etc." is off-topic.

Should we change our example in the Skeptics FAQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the [FAQ](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq) to reflect this (and also with a few more sites that got opened since the last edit):

> If your question is not about *a particular claim*, or if it is about research-level science, the following sites may be better suited for your needs:
>
> - Physics - [Physics - Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)
> - Fitness & fitness-related nutrition - [Fitness and Nutrition - Stack Exchange](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/)
> - Biology - [Biology - Stack Exchange](http://biology.stackexchange.com)
> - Astronomy - [Astronomy - Stack Exchange](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/)
> - Philosophy - [Philosophy - Stack Exchange](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/)
>
> The full list is available on [the main Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

The purpose of this paragraph is to send people without a claim to the appropriate site (not to send people with claims to other sites).

Answer (score 0):

Yes please!

Especially because the questions that get asked on Skeptics often focus on debunking some kind of myth, which isn't our purpose. So I think it would be best if the mods asked if we wanted a question before considering to migrate it to us, though we haven't any real problems so far.

Comment: Maybe it's not clear enough, but the point of the quoted excerpt is basically to say "if your question is about peer-reviewed literature, or if it's not about debunking something, but it's about nutrition then you're better off asking on F&N."

Comment: While it may say that, that doesn't mean the question will actually be about that. Though not migrated from Skeptics, we've had our fair share of "Is aspartame bad for you?" and the like. Either way, I expect it would be highly unlikely questions from Skeptics would be wanted on Fitness.SE

Comment: @IvoFlipse this Q is about the FAQ notice, not question migration.

Comment: @Sancho well, general nutrition questions are OT both here and on F&N. In any case, Ivo's answer is clearly about migration and not about asking questions

Comment: @Sancho not that I know of - the two things are completely unrelated

Comment: Well in any case, I'd prefer if you didn't point users to our site for questions solely based on Nutrition. Because skeptical questions about nutrition aren't welcome on Fitness.SE, which makes it unlikely a lot of your users should be pointed here for that goal